# d3 js expandable and collapsable tree structure

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree, label, visualization

I am trying to generate a expandable and collapsable horizontal tree structure for showing execution time of some groups.

Here is my structure of data

Group1
  - Artifact1 
         - time taken
  - Artifact2
         - time taken to execute
  .
  .
  .
Group2
  - Artifact3
         - time taken
  - Artifact4
         - time taken
  .
  .
  .

Ideally I want to display all groups as Rectangles and when user clicks on one rectangle(group) it should expand all artifacts.

I am looking into this example: https://github.com/lbrucher/d3-tree-heatmap:

[image]

The issue with this example is when I have more groups, the page expand crazily and labels inside boxes disappear. Also I have around 30 groups so want to display 4 or 5 boxes per row

Can some help me on providing some ideas on this issue

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can create two diagrams of the tree that you want:

- one that displays all labels clearly, but doesn't fit in the screen (its width is much larger than screen width):
- another that fits the screen, but doesn't display labels.

And then you allow user to scroll down the second diagram, similar to this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/bunkat/1962173): (ofcourse, in your case, diagrams will look differently)

---

[image]

Comment: very interesting example @VividD...had not come across it...interesting possibilities...thanks!